Zetasketch for Google / GCP Do we have something similar for AWS or Athena
I was working on project where sketch sent by hll_count.init() is passed to zetasketch which returns state.
Is there any function similar to zetasketch for AWS or Athena as to when I get the sketch using a query ( approx_set) I need the state which is similar to zetasketch???
Also approx_set returns hll where as hll_count.init returns hll++ that's why I cannot reuse zetasketch in AWS
Or is there a function which returns hll++ in AWS ?
Similar to Zetasketch Library in AWS or for Athena
